# unable to list the properties of azure ad user (createddatetime)

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I have many users in my Azure AD tenant, I want to collect the data of the users when they are created.

I am able to get the user details by running `Get-AzureADUser`. So, I just modified the command as

```
Get-AzureADUser | Select-Object, Mail, createdDateTime
```

But this returned details but the createdDateTime field was empty. After some research I found that createdDateTime is an **extension attribute**.

I found this command `Get-AzureADUserExtension` but now my question is I want to get the list of users with their email and the created date time.

Any script to achieve my scenario?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

To get the **`createdDateTime`** of Azure AD Users with email address, I tried the below script:

```
$result = @()
$AAD_users = Get-AzureADUser -All:$true
foreach ($AAD_User in $AAD_users) {
$info = [PSCustomObject]@{
Email     = $AAD_User.mail
CreationDateTime  = (Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $AAD_User.ObjectId).Get_Item("createdDateTime")
}
$result+= $info
}
$result
```

I am able to get the list of users with **`createdDateTime`** successfully like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not using the Az Module as its end-of-life is not that far away anymore. It got replaced by the mgGraph cmdlets (install-module microsoft.graph).

There I can do:

```
get-mguser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq 'myName@myCompany.com'" -Property CreatedDateTime,Mail,UserPrincipalName
```

The property CreatedDateTime does not need to be expanded but it must be explicitly listed as property to retrieve, otherwise I won't get the value. I think you can do simliar with the Az cmdlets or otherwise switch to the MgGraph cmdlets which you have to do anyways until 2024.

Comment: Thank you so much but my requirement is to use az module as of now:)